# WordPress Multisite - Multiple subfolders for blogs

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, apache, virtual-hosts

I created a network in `blog.animals.com`, the network is running fine. I can set up blogs like `blog.animals.com/chimpanse`. This is also working. I like to have multiple (2) subdirectories for each blog, e.g.

- `blog.animals.com/apes/chimpanse`
- `blog.animals.com/cats/birma`

On an address like `blog.animals.com/apes` should be nothing, it should redirect to `blog.animals.com/apes/chimpanse` and so on.

I tried to achieve this on a local MAMP environment with `sunrise.php` ([Domain Mapping plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)), `VirtualHost` entries in `httpd-vhosts.conf` and/or `.htaccess`, unfortunately with no success.

Later on it should run on a real Apache server.

Is this possible at all? If yes, how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a sub folder install for each type of animal.

To do this you need to create a folder in the root of your server called apes and another one called cats and than transfer the wordpress files to each of these folders and install.

This way you can have two subsites within the same domain

blog.animals.com/apes

blog.animals.com/cats